# RxJava - How to take the first element of a list and return it as Observable

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

Let's take this observable:

```
Observable<List<UserProfile>> findUser =service.getUserProfiles()
```

How can I transform it so it returns the first element as an Observable (and not an Observable list just containing the first element). I tried `first()` and `takeFirst()` but it still returns a list.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Map it!

```
Observable<List<UserProfile>> findUser = service.getUserProfiles();
Observable<UserProfile> firstUser = findUser
    .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
    .map(list -> list.get(0));
```

Comment: Thanks. What happens if `list.isEmpty()` returns true?

Comment: In this case the "filter" observable won't emit any items. Therefore the following map() won't be called, since the filter observable didn't emit any items.

Answer (score 3):

Without see what's going on `getUserProfile()` it's complicated, but what about this :

```
@Test
public void getFirstUser(){
    Observable<List<Integer>> findUser =Observable.just(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    Observable<Integer> user = findUser
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .first();
    user.subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```